# How to flatten string column in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, flatten

```
                            a                                                                                                                               b
[{'npi': [1013006469, 1003263552], 'tin': {'type': 'npi', 'value': '1013006469'}}, {'npi': [1487607883], 'tin': {'type': 'npi', 'value': '1487607883'}}]    0
[{'npi': [1275086126], 'tin': {'type': 'npi', 'value': '1275086126'}}, {'npi': [1285698381], 'tin': {'type': 'npi', 'value': '1285698381'}}]                2
```

above is input dataframe from which I want to flatten **'a'** column which is in the form of string.
I want following output

```
    a_npi       a_tin_type  a_tin_value     b
    1013006469  npi         1013006469      0
    1003263552  npi         1013006469      0
    1487607883  npi         1487607883      0
    1275086126  npi         1275086126      2
    1285698381  npi         1285698381      2
```

following is code that I've but it returns all null values

```
inp_sch = spark.read.json(df.select(col('a').alias('jsonbody')).rdd.map(lambda x: x.jsonbody)).schema
inp_json = df.select('*', from_json('a', inp_sch).alias('jsonstr'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**from_json** function for **tin** in pyspark will get it done.

Example

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('col1', StringType(), True),
        StructField('col2', StringType(), True)
    ]
)

df.withColumn("data", from_json("data", schema))\
    .select(col('data.*'))\
    .show()
```

and the first column with Array, use **explode**() function similarly.